# Ошибка springSecurityFilterChain

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

Ошибка -

```
 by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate Filter registration for 'springSecurityFilterChain'. Check to ensure the Filter is only configured once.
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.registerFilter(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.insertSpringSecurityFilterChain(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java:151)
```

Не знаете из-за чего я вроде все правильно написал

SecurityWebApplicationInitializer

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.config;

  import org.springframework.security.web.context.*;    

  public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer    
      extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {    

  }
```

ServletInitializer

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.config;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Value("${spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size}")

    private int maxFileSize;

    @Value("${spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size}")

    private int maxRequestSize;

    @Autowired

    private Environment environment;

    @Override

    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

        return new Class[]{HibernateConfig.class};

    }

    @Override

    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

        return new Class[]{WebMvcConfig.class};

    }

    @Override

    protected String[] getServletMappings() {

        return new String[]{"/"};

    }
}
```

WebMVCConfig

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.config;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "adil.java.schoolmaven")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size:1024}")

    private int maxUploadFileSize;

    @Bean

    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css");
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();

        resolver.setMaxUploadSize(maxUploadFileSize * 1024);

        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean

    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigIn() {

        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

    }
}

    //@Override
    //public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    //  registry.jsp().prefix("/WEB-INF/views/").suffix(".jsp");
    //}
    // @Bean
    // public MessageSource messageSource() {
    // ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new
    // ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    // messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    // return messageSource;
    // }



    /*@Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }*/
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;    
//import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.*;    
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;    
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;    
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.*;  
//import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;    
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;  
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;    
@EnableWebSecurity    
@ComponentScan("adil.java.schoolmaven")    
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {    

@Bean    
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {    
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();    
    manager.createUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()  
    .username("adil").password("123456").roles("ADMIN").build());    
    return manager;    
}    

@Override    
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    

      http.authorizeRequests().  
      antMatchers("/index", "/user","/").permitAll()  
      .antMatchers("/admin").authenticated()  
      .and()  
      .formLogin()  
      .loginPage("/login")  
      .and()  
      .logout()  
      .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));  
}    
}
```

Web.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <error-page>

        <location>/errors</location>
    </error-page>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>




</web-app>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Надо было удалить

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```